# Lazy Loading Pagination in Kendo UI Grid in Java

Tags: java, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, lazy-loading

I am using Kendo UI Grid to represent around 21000 data records. I am having Java on server side to send JSON data and Kendo UI in JSP as to render grid. I want o know that is there any implementation through which I can load a particular records in grid rather than fetching all at once, also loading all at once consumes much time.

Require an implementation where I can send page number, records numbers etc to be fetched from server.

Answer (score 0):

You may try grid virtualization with remote data from server. It enables loading of the data only when the user scrolls thr grid. check this for a JSP based example: http://demos.telerik.com/jsp-ui/grid/virtualization-remote-data

Comment: thanks, but I am looking for the pagination technique in which if user click on 5 it will fetch 41-50 number of record in grid.

Comment: In that case, I think you should consider server paging as in http://demos.telerik.com/jsp-ui/grid/remote-data-binding. I see a request/response on network debugging whenever an index is clicked.